# Integral of $\frac{e^x}{5+2e^x}$

Tags: integration

Regarding the integral of this term$\frac{e^x}{5+2e^x}=\frac{e^x}{2(\frac{5}{2}+e^x)}$

Is the answer $\frac{1}{2} \ln(\frac{5}{2} +e^x)$ or $\frac{1}{2} \ln(5+2e^x)$?
When I substitute $u= \frac{5}{2}+e^x$ I get the first one, when it's $u=5+2e^x$, then it is the second one...

Comment: These two are equal up to a constant, namely $\frac{1}{2}\ln 2$ so these are both correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$C + \frac 12 \ln(5+2e^x ) =C + \frac 12\ln[2(\frac 52 +e^x)]=C +\frac12\ln 2 + \frac 12 \ln\left(\frac 52 + e^x\right)  $$ the two antiderivatives differ by a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Call $u = 5+2e^x$ right off the bat. So ${\rm d}u = 2e^x\,{\rm d}x$, and: $$\int \frac{e^x}{5+2e^x}\,{\rm d}x = \int\frac{1}{2u}\,{\rm d}u = \frac{1}{2}\ln u + c = \frac{1}{2}\ln(5+2e^x)+ c, \quad c \in \Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is both. Differentiate and you will get the original integrand in both cases.

Why? $\frac{1}{2}\ln{(\frac{5}{2} + e^x)} = \frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{5+ 2e^x}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}(\ln{(5+ 2e^x)} - \ln{2})$, which differs from the other answer by a constant. Therefore, both antiderivatives are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dx}\left[\frac12\log(5+2e^x)\right] = \frac{2e^x}{2(5+2e^x)}=\frac{e^x}{5+2e^x}, $$
it follows that $\frac12\log(5+2e^x)$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{e^x}{5+2e^x}.$